# How to divide bill of amount x between different people with usage of different days.

Tags: complex-analysis, quadratics

For example: Total electricity bill is $19930 for 60 days (~i.e 2 months) for a particular house.

Now there are 7 people who lived in the home for different days.

- Alice: 60 days
- Bob: 60 days
- Catharine: 45 days
- Douglous: 45 days
- Eve: 45 days
- Frank: 15 days
- George: 15 days

How much amount each person have to pay for this total bill.

I tried dividing total bill of 19930/60 = 332.16 332.16 of single day. between 7 people.
and

332.16/7 = **47.45 per person for single day.**

Now George have to pay 47.45 * 15 (the days for which she lived in the house) =  ~711

Same for Frank = ~711

For Catharine, Douglous and Eve the amount will be 47.45 * 45 = 2135.25

and for Alice and Bob it will be 47.45 * 60 = $ 2847

But when I add this amount of all persons
2847*2 + 2135 * 3 + 711*2 **!=** ~19930

Why is this happening?

Comment: You have tried what??

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: You must divide by the total of all the 'people -days". See the answer below.

Comment: The mistake you made is that you divided the sum by $60$, when you should have divided by $285$, which is the total number of person-nights stayed.

Answer (score 1):

You could weight each person's contributions according to the length of their stay.

Find the total number $T$ of "people-days". For your example this is $60+60+...$.

Then a person who has lived in the house for $D$ days could be expected to pay $$\frac{Dx}{T}$$ out of a bill of amount $x$.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people are disliking this question but I couldn't help myself from arguing my way into the answer here. So let's see.

Suppose you have $N$ people, and that person number $i$ has lived in the house for $n_i$ days in in the house. To be fair, the amount $x_i$ a person has to pay should be proportional to this $n_i$, that is, $x_i = x \,n_i$ for some value of $x$,  and thus the total amount of money to be paid $x_{tot}$ is given by the formula

$$x_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^N x\, n_i = x \sum_{i=1}^N \, n_i.$$

We can find $x$ simply by rewriting

$$x  = \frac{x_{tot}}{\sum_{i=1}^N n_i},$$

so that person number $i$ has to pay

$$x_i = x \,n_i = \frac{n_i}{\sum_{i=1}^N n_i} x_{tot}. $$

Now you fill in the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $p$ be the price for one person in one day .

Then we have

$$60p+60p+45p+45p+45p+15p+15p=19930 .$$

Hence $285 p =19930 .$

Now you can determine $p$.

For example: the amount of Alice is $60 \cdot \frac{19930}{285}.$